# Issue with cursor execute

Tags: attributes, sqlite3-python

**I have created a database. When I run the following script I get no error:**
'''
import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import Error

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('Test.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute('''INSERT INTO Movies (title, year, hdd, bluray, dvd, digital, watched, numcopies)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)''', ('TestMovie', 1989, 'N', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 1))
cur.execute('''INSERT INTO Movies (title, year, hdd, bluray, dvd, digital, watched, numcopies)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)''', ('NewMovie', 1991, 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'N', 2))
conn.commit()

cur.execute('SELECT title, year, hdd, bluray, dvd, digital, watched, numcopies FROM Movies')
```

'''

**However, when I run the following I get an error:**
'''
conn = sqlite3.connect('Test.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor

```
# Welcome screen and options
print("Welcome to Movie List")
Title = input("Enter name of movie: ")

cur.execute('SELECT title, year, hdd, bluray, dvd, digital, watched, numcopies FROM Movies')
```

'''

**This is the error.**
"Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\bible\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\PY4E Training\Movie List\MovieList.py", line 14, in 
cur.execute('SELECT title, year, hdd, bluray, dvd, digital, watched, numcopies FROM Movies')
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'execute'"

****I do not understand why it works in one and not the other.

As shown I tried running a test version that worked. But when I plug it into the real version (using same test database) it does not work.
I would like to search and retrieve existing data from database.****